# Sticking arbitrary attribute on an element in Freestyle CSS

Tags: ios, pixate

Is there a way to stick an arbitrary attribute on some element using Freestyle CSS? Like this:

```
label {
    some-new-attribute: "Value";
}
```

It could be added as a user defined runtime attribute.